# Django model set lookup very slow

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm getting a very slow lookup in my Django models.

I have two tables:

```
class Scan(models.Model):
    scan_name = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True, validators=[alphanumeric_plus_validator])

class ScanProcessingInfo(models.Model):
    scan_name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    processing_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    in_progress = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

When I perform the following operation to get a list of all Scan objects which have a ScanProcessingInfo for a specific processing_name:

```
scans = models.Scan.objects.all()

        scan_set = []

        for scan in scans:
            if self.set_type_definition.test_scan(scan, self.arg1, self.arg2):
                scan_set.append(scan)


(test_scan routes to)

def get_proc_info_been_done(scan, spd_name):
    try:
        proc_info = models.ScanProcessingInfo.objects.get(scan_name = scan.scan_name)
    except models.ScanProcessingInfo.DoesNotExist:
        proc_info = None

    if proc_info == None:
        return False

    return not proc_info.in_progress
```

the request takes about 10 seconds.  There are 300 Scans in total and 10 ScanProcessingInfos.  The db backend is an RDS MySQL db.  I also expect someone will tell me off for using strings for the cross-table identifiers, but I doubt that's the cause here.

I'm sure I'm doing something obvious wrong, but would appreciate a pointer, thank you.

Comment: You should use foreign key relations and indexes in your models.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're asking is how to get all Scans for which a matching ScanProcessingInfo exists.

The first thing to do is to declare the actual relationship. You don't need to change your database (you should, but you don't have to); you can use your existing underlying field, but just tell Django to treat it as a foreign key.

```
class ScanProcessingInfo(models.Model):
    scan = models.ForeignKey('Scan', to_field='scan_name', db_field='scan_name', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

Now you can use this relationship to get all the scans in one go:

```
scan_set = Scan.objects.exclude(scanprocessinginfo=None)
```

**Edit**

To get all matching objects with a specific attribute, use the double-underscore syntax:

```
scan_set = Scan.objects.filter(scanprocessinginfo__processing_name=spd_name)
```

Comment: Thank you - I do need to know how to get the list of Scan objects which have an associated ScanProcessingInfo object with a specific processing_name

Comment: Sorry to keep peppering questions, but I also need to get the set which do *not* have a processingInfo with a specific name - could you assist me with that?

Comment: You can use `exclude` as in the first example.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Many-to-one relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/).

```
scan_name = ForeignKey(Scan, related_name='processing_infos',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```